# trouble with getting elasticsearch started: ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.rest.XContentRestResponse]

Tags: elasticsearch

I've installed elastic search using homebrew on a mac and also sintalled the river-jdbc plugin.  When I try to start elastic search I get the following error, any advice on how to get it running?:=

```
[2014-09-08 13:56:39,133][INFO ][node                     ] [Marius St. Croix] version[1.2.1], pid[48336], build[6c95b75/2014-06-03T15:02:52Z]
[2014-09-08 13:56:39,133][INFO ][node                     ] [Marius St. Croix] initializing ...
[2014-09-08 13:56:39,144][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Marius St. Croix] loaded [river-jdbc, marvel], sites [marvel]
{1.2.1}: Initialization Failed ...
- ExecutionError[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/rest/XContentRestResponse]
    NoClassDefFoundError[org/elasticsearch/rest/XContentRestResponse]
        ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.rest.XContentRestResponse]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your elasticsearch version? Maybe they have fixed it for **FS River Plugin 1.2.0**  / **elasticsearch 1.2.0**.

References

- [FileSystem River for Elasticsearch
  issue#67](https://github.com/dadoonet/fsriver/issues/67)
- [FileSystem River for Elasticsearch 
  issue#68](https://github.com/dadoonet/fsriver/issues/68)

Comment: it was version 1.2.1 ... I uninstalled and reinstalled and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Elasticsearch 1.5.2 on Linux and receiving this error, it's best to use OpenJDK instead of Oracle's Java.

From what I've tested, it does like to use jdk1.8.0_11 or jre1.8.0_45. I haven't tried v1.7.x versions of Oracle's Java, however.